# Memory leaks in ipod - 100% leak while using instruments and iPod

Tags: xcode, memory-leaks

```
 -(NSString*)readTextColumnWithIndex:(int)index {
    char* val = (char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement,index);
    if (val==NULL) {
        return nil;
    }
    return [NSString stringWithUTF8String:val];
}
```

I have 100% leak at return [NSString stringWithUTF8String:val];. Not sure how to fix them. I believe only alloc, retain etc could end up in memory leaks. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: But you didn't, did you.

Answer (score 0):

`[NSString stringWithUTF8String:val]` is the statement that created the object that is leaking - you need to see what happens to it next.

Are you retaining the `NSString` returned by `readTextColumnWithIndex:` somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

```
-(NSDictionary*)loadDataRow:(SqlQuery*)q {

    return [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:      [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[q readIntColumn]],
        @"TOCID",[q readTextColumn],@"SubChapter_Name",[q readTextColumn],
        @"HtmlFileName",[q readTextColumn],@"ImageName",[q readTextColumn],
        @"RefsTitleSection",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",
                             [q readIntColumn]],@"PageId",
        nil];
```

}

This is where it is called. readIntColumn in turn calls readTextColumnWithIndex and NSDictionary is returned back to an the caller method

```
chap_Arr = nil;
while([query step]) {
    ChapName = [query readTextColumn];
     chap_Arr = [mData objectForKey:ChapName];
    if (!chap_Arr) {
        chap_Arr = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
        [mData setObject:chap_Arr forKey:ChapName];
    }

    [chap_Arr addObject:[self loadDataRow:query]];

}
```

I am not sure how i can release the chap_Arr as it is in a loop. I do have an RELEASE_SAFELY in dealloc.